# Loop Iterations and arithmetic operations on csv document with Python

Tags: python, list, csv, nested-loops

I've been working for a while on the problem I'm about to present and have tried to solve it resolving to mailing lists and other online resources but at the end all my efforts have been unsuccesful, so far. That's why I'm asking for your precious time to help me accomplish the following task:

I'm working on a dataset stored as an sqlite database that I converted into an csv document, in order to process it better with Python 2.7.
The data is arranged in a comma separated csv format and reports hits of a sensor along with other info. It comes in 8 comma-separated fields of different data types, i.e. string, int and float. I'm only interested in the second field, which is where the datetime of the recorded hit was stored in a UNIX timestamp format and in milliseconds. 
Unfortunately the sensors' builtin clock failed to remain up-to-date and I was only able to recover an approximated corrected timestamp for a given day by other means.

Here's an example of how the data looks like:

```
sensor_ID,timestamp,z,w,k,j,n,human-readable_datetime
651,956684876150254,-0.1692345,0.623286,0.01442572,0.81455,-0.145732,"2000-01-01 00:01:16"
651,956684936161895,0.00526153,0.999893,0.00998516,0.898215,-0.155301,"2000-01-01 00:02:16"
651,956684996173593,0.00526153,0.999893,0.00988516,0.865215,-0.154301,"2000-01-01 00:03:16"
651,956685056185292,0.00526153,0.999893,0.00978676,0.883215,-0.159301,"2000-01-01 00:04:16"
651,956685116196912,0.00526153,0.999893,0.00922469,0.809862,-0.158607,"2000-01-01 00:05:16"
```

What I want to do is the following:

1) compare each of the timestamps in column #2 to a value corresponding to the retrieved approximately corrected timestamp, which is stored in a separate file. This means: for each timestamp 'x' in column #2 --> subtract it to the correct timestamp 'y' --> IF abs(y-x) > 60 seconds THEN CONTINUE (to step 2) ELSE QUIT

2) once one match is found and the subtraction operation outputs a value > 60 secs --> add a given fixed value (that I will call the 'syncing_value') to all the timestamps in the file, both backwards and forwards, and do this as long as they remain coherent, i.e., as long as the timestamps are out-of-date. This is because some sensors' clock would stop synchronising but would go back to work normally after a software update.

3) write file to output and exit

For the sake of simplicity I'll attach the pseudocode I used, as regarding the actual code I've got so many different almost-working alternatives, I wouldn't know which one to present. I hope you understand.

This is my pseudocode, which somehow lacks of some fundamental features I mentioned above:

```
import csv

for row in data:

    for x in row[1]:

        if x <= y:

            for i in range(x,len(data)-1):

                i = i + syncing_value

        else:

            exit
```

I really hope that what I want to achieve is clear to you and would really appreciate your help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

filename = 'csv.txt'              #csv file to read/write to
timestamp = 956684876150324       #correct timestamp 
syncing_value = 90 

#read contents of csv file into list
data = list(csv.reader(open(filename)))  

#compare second column of every row after header (data[1:]) to correct timestamp
#if any differ more than 60 from correct timestamp, add syncing_value to all timestamps
#in file, and save changes.
if any(abs(int(row[1])-timestamp) > 60 for row in data[1:]):
    for row in data[1:]:
        row[1] = int(row[1]) + syncing_value
    csv_writer = csv.writer(open(filename,'w'))
    csv_writer.writerows(data)
```

Comment: Thank you @mtadd, your code works well. I was clearly getting the  syntax to build nested loops wrong. Now what if in the same database, at some point, the timestamp processed is actually already sync'd? Unfortunately, I'm aware of a few cases where this happens.

Comment: i just noted that your database is in sqlite.  python has good libraries for interfacing directly with sqlite databases, and you may be more comfortable performing such logic in SQL rather than using python with flatfile (csv) formats.

Comment: I'll eventually have to convert the sqlite database to csv in order to be able to run some R scripts and that's why I thought I'd do well by doing the conversion before the syncing, but I might as well follow your advice and look into python's sqlite support. Cheers!